# Sql symfony2 result pb

Tags: symfony

I need to calculate the amount of a table according to certain constraint

```
SELECT SUM(montant_ht) FROM rt_restauration  WHERE statut <> ('creee')  AND (affectation_jour1 NOT IN ('Pas de table disponible') OR affectation_jour1 IS NULL)
```

In symfony

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->select('SUM(r.montantHt)')
            ->where('r.statut <> :nostatut')
            ->setParameter('nostatut', Restauration::STATUT_CREEE);

$qb->andWhere( $qb->expr()->orx($qb->expr()->notIn('r.affectation_jour1',':nosaf'),
$qb->expr()->isNull('r.affectation_jour1')))->setParameter('nosaf',$qb->expr()->literal('Pas de table disponible'));

$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

But here is its not the same result?

Thank you for your help

Comment: check your query with `$qb->getDQL()` method and compare both query.

Comment: Try `->setParameter('nosaf', ['Pas de table disponible']);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you use NOT IN for a single value
(Sorry I don't use expr)

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
     ->select('SUM(r.montantHt)')
    ->where('r.statut <> :nostatut')
    ->setParameter('nostatut', Restauration::STATUT_CREEE)
    ->andWhere('r.affectation_jour1 <> :nosaf OR r.affectation_jour1 IS NULL')
    ->setParameter('nosaf','Pas de table disponible');
```

For multiple values (or signle value in array) it should be

```
->andWhere('r.affectation_jour1 NOT IN (:nosaf)')
```

But note than you should check that your array is never empty